# Mysql detect doublon with order by date

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

I have a problem with this request :
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbr_doublon, tel, dateippo FROM vici GROUP BY tel HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

[image]

I want to obtien this result :

[image]

^the result will have the duplicata only with date tried
please help

------------------------- table data

```
id  tel            dateippo     status  lead_id 
1   11111111111     2017-01-02  ok      4   y
2   11111111111     2017-01-26  na      5   y
3   11111111111     2017-01-28  rep     4   n
4   22222222222     2017-01-10  ok      7   y
```

result i want :

```
id  tel             dateippo    status  lead_id 
1   11111111111     2017-01-02  ok      4   
4   22222222222     2017-01-10  ok      7
```

test with the status firstly if egal to "ok" and order by dateippo
else order by dateippo

thnx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get rows with max id for each tel, use this:

```
select
    t.*
from vici t
inner join (
    select tel, max(id) id
    from vici
    group by tel
) t2 on t.tel = t2.tel
and t.id = t2.id;
```

#### EDIT 1:

if it's based on dateippo, just replace id with dateippo like this:

```
select
    t.*
from vici t
inner join (
    select tel, max(dateippo) dateippo
    from vici
    group by tel
) t2 on t.tel = t2.tel
and t.dateippo = t2.dateippo;
```

#### EDIT 2:

To order by status = 'ok' first, and order by date second,

```
select
    t.*
from vici t
inner join (
    select tel, max(id) id
    from vici
    group by tel
) t2 on t.tel = t2.tel
and t.id = t2.id
order by t.status <> 'ok', t.dateippo;
```

#### EDIT 3:

```
select
    t.*
from vici t
inner join (
    select 
        tel,
        case when count(status = 'ok') > 1 then 
            max(case when status = 'ok' then dateippo end) 
        else max(dateippo) end dateippo
    from vici
    group by tel
) t2 on t.tel = t2.tel
and t.dateippo = t2.dateippo;
select * from vici;
```

or based on id:

```
select
    t.*
from vici t
inner join (
    select 
        tel,
        case when count(status = 'ok') > 1 then 
            max(case when status = 'ok' then id end) 
        else max(id) end id
    from vici
    group by tel
) t2 on t.tel = t2.tel
and t.id = t2.id;
select * from vici;

+------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+
| id   | tel         | dateippo   | status | lead_id |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+
|    1 | 11111111111 | 2017-01-02 | ok     |       4 |
|    4 | 22222222222 | 2017-01-10 | ok     |       7 |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please another question, if i want to add a critaria, i explain : order by status = 'ok' first, and order by date second, i test this but he's return one row "  select t.* from vici t inner join ( select tel, max(dateippo) as dateippo from vici group by tel ) t2 on t.tel = t2.tel AND cloturee = 'y' and t.dateippo = t2.dateippo AND status = 'ok'  "

Comment: @MoHamedNejjAr - See the last query

Comment: thnx for reply, its work but not perfectly : it return 2 rows, one with status = 'ok' , and one row with date tried desc but status = 'rep', i want the result with If status = 'ok' return duplicate data, else return duplicate data order by date

Comment: @MoHamedNejjAr Please post sample data and your expected output as a *text table* (not an image) in the question to clarify

Comment: Thnx you ... work perfectly .. i will adapt it to my database prod  .. 